# run timer every 10 minutes from the hour

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a vb.net application with a timer that runs every 10 minutes.

How can i make it run every 10 minutes from the hour.

for example, if i start the application at *`16:03`* it will run every 10 minutes from then. How can i make it run every 10 minutes from the next 10

for exmaple, the application starts at `*16:03*`, the timer will next tick at `*16:10*` then `*16:20*` rather than `*16:13*`, then `*16:23`* and so on...

Comment: Set the first timer interval to be shorter than 10 minutes. If your app is started at 16:03, set the first interval to be 7 minutes instead of 10, and then use 10 after that first interval is completed.

Comment: it wont always be started at the same time though

Comment: It doesn't matter. If it's started at 16:04, set the initial interval to 6 minutes. If it's started at 16:08, set it to 2 minutes. **Adjust the initial interval** to get on the cycle you want, and then go back to the normal cycle's intervals.

Comment: i dont want to have to set the interval everytime its opened

Comment: If you want it to run every 10 minutes as you say, you have no choice but to set the interval on the first run. There's nothing complicated about doing so - why don't you want to do it? It's simple math. You asked the question, and that's the answer. If you don't want to listen, then apparently you're asking something else and should edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Set the timer to 1 minute, check if the current number of minutes ends with a `0`, and if so do the thing.
- Alternatively, on startup set the timer to X of minutes, where X is `10 - last digit of current time`. On the first timer tick, do the thing, set the timer to 10 minutes and don't touch it any more.

Comment: what do you mean by last digit of current time ?

Comment: @user2710234 if the current time is 11:23 the last digit is 3